# Title Area modern ui pages does not load

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, reactjs

I have two modern UI pages `Test1` and `Test2`. In `Test1` page, I am using SPFx webpart to hide control on particular pages. I am using CSS:

```
global {
    div[class^='pageTitle_'] {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

when I navigate to another page `Test2` where I have not used any SPFx control and its a simple modern page it inherit same CSS and page title gets hide until I refresh it manually.

Comment: Can you add more details and code to the question ?

Comment: added some detail

Comment: just to confirm that it's a webpart and not an extension, right ?

Comment: webpart but i am omly using in one page

Comment: then this should not happen. can you try removing global from css and check ?

Comment: if i remove global css does not work

Comment: added answer. check and let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file , let's say **customCSS.css** inside your component folder and paste the below code :

```
div[class^='pageTitle_']{
  display: none ;
}
```

Now in your main .ts file call this css file with the following syntax on top of the code :

```
require("../../webparts/WebpartName/components/customCSS.css");
```

To refresh the page on load only once, paste the below code in componentDidMount :

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this , but it still affect  this css in another pages as well

Comment: This is so strange behaviour as I am using same code in all of my web parts and it hides the page title only for the page on which the web part has been inserted.

Comment: i added this css it hide the page title but it also hide page title from another page where this webpart is not present it happen only if i navigate through pages from navigation ,if manualyy refresh the pages it donot happen

Comment: can i refresh page once when i navigate to page for workaround

Comment: yes that seems to be workaround for now. Also it's not happening for me even if I navigate to other page from navigation.

Comment: ok , i thought of developing a spfx solution and add in normal mui pages which will refresh the page , but want to check how can i load page or css on componentDidMount()

Comment: In this case you can use window.location.reload(); to refresh the page

Comment: i tried this,if i write this in  componentDidMount() it keeps on refreshing

Comment: updated the answer . Please check if this resolves the issue.

Comment: it does not load page tried above code in didmount

Comment: thnaks i ahave modified above script and it worked

Comment: That's great. Good to know that it worked